# What is the best way to create a table with 800 columns in a single script?

Tags: oracle

I prepared a script to create a table with 800 columns but SQLPlus and SQL Developer are not reading the whole script as they probably read only 7499/2499 characters max. As an alternative I am thinking to divide the script into an initial create script with 200 columns and then alter table to add remaining columns in 200 chunks. My question is that what is the best practice to achieve this? Are there any cleaner alternatives. I searched google but could not find the relevant answers and most of them got closed by suggestion that the table should at first place not have these many columns and it is a design issue.

Note: I am trying to replicate a scenario in a legacy system by creating a local database. So I don't have the option to denormalize.

---

### What is the best way to create a table with 800 columns in a single script?

Comment: I doubt you'll find "best practices" to do this, since creating such a table it in the first place is clearly not advised at all. Your split approach should work though, so why are you looking for alternatives?

Comment: It seemed to me like I am going on a wrong path and there will be a cleaner approach. In case I want to replicate my schema in another database then I won't be able to run a single script to create a replica. That seemed unnatural to me.

Comment: >> prepared a script to create a table with 800 columns but SQLPlus and >>SQL Developer are not reading the whole script
What version of both tools did you try? You should be able to run your script, @my_very_bad_script.sql

Comment: The most columns that I have ever seen in a table was 225 columns with 25 indexes. For some reason there were some performance issues... :-) While I can't imagine wanting 800 columns in a table, your approach seems to be the best one that I can think of. What does the select statement look like???

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - I downloaded them last week from oracle website. So those should be of latest version. I will recheck once again if I was making some other mistake but I doubt that. How many characters can I put in my create table script?

Comment: @Gandolf989 - The script is nearly 30k characters between create table and end bracket.

Comment: Have you tried running it directly in sqlplus? I don't think that the size of the files is that relevant. Take a look at scripts in the $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin folder. There are a number of scripts over 200K.

Comment: you can put in as many as you want, just don't load the file into the editor, call it by reference using the @ syntax

Comment: and if we give you pause on creating a table with 800 columns, then that MIGHT be a good thing

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - What you said is correct. Simply calling the script using @ works. Today I tried again after correcting other errors like duplicate column names and column length issues. It worked. Somehow yesterday it was throwing error saying script truncated after 7499 characters which lead me to believe that it takes only 7.5k characters from the script. Is there a way to mark your comment as a correct answer? I am new to stackexchange so not sure if we can only mark a answer as correct or if comment is allowed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to run a very long script is not to load it into the editor, any editor.

Just reference it via @ and run it

So @my_script.sql and execute that.

Answer (score 2):

I had to try it myself, because I did not believe SQL*Plus can not handle this. Apparently, it can.

Script for generating the create statement:

```
[oracle@ora71 ~]$ cat generate.sql
set echo off feedback off heading off pages 0
spool create.sql
select text from
(
        select 'create table t1 (' as text, 0 as position from dual union
        select 'columnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' || rownum || ' number, '  as text, rownum as position from dual connect by level < 800 union
        select 't date);' as text, null as position from dual
) order by position nulls last;
spool off
exit
```

Generating the DDL:

```
[oracle@ora71 ~]$ sqlplus -s bp/bp @generate.sql > /dev/null
[oracle@ora71 ~]$ wc -c create.sql
64881 create.sql
[oracle@ora71 ~]$ tr -d '[:space:]' < create.sql | wc -c
25481
```

64881 characters, or 25481 without spaces.

Creating the table without any problem:

```
[oracle@ora71 ~]$ sqlplus -s bp/bp @create.sql

Table created.

exit
```

Comment: Your answer is correct and that is exactly what I was looking for but thatjeffsmith answered it first so will mark his comment as the correct answer. Thanks a lot for your help. At first place I had put this question for the very same reason because it seemed strange to me that oracle can't handle a script of size more than 7.5k.

Comment: If you found Balazs' post helpful, you can upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

Been there, done that my friend! I had to do it with a system that had 35K (not a typo - that's 35,000) fields - basically arrays of arrays.

I didn't even **attempt** to recreate the system on my SQL Server database. I connected using my development environment (Delphi at the time, ah... those were the days...) and chopped up the table record by record.

I designed incrementally. I outlined a normalised, multi-table approach (rough draft) and then, on my first phase, I'd take in some of the major fields and put them into my normalised structure.

Gradually, I slotted the 35K fields into more and more tables (there weren't 35K fields - or anything like it - in my new database, all tables) until I had put all of the data into the new system.

I was really (really) proud of the fact that I wrote a function of 650,000 lines of code (actually wrote a programme to write the code) and it worked **first time!!!**.

What's your dev. environment? I would suggest that the above approach is the best one. Failing that, can you take a .csv (or similar) dump of the data and then work with that text file? I had a Delphi driver for my old system, so I could communicate directly, but I realise that with legacy systems, this isn't always possible. Final question: is this ETL process a one-off, or do you have to do it on a regular basis?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the detailed feedback. This is actually a one time job. Let me explain. I mainly work on Salesforce where we have objects which actually corresponds to oracle tables in the backend. One of our objects because of bad design has hit the Salesforce limitation of 800 fields max. Now we are thinking of redesigning it but to do that we need to perform analysis on the current data in the table which is around 900k. Can't do that in excel and will face other issues if we do that in Salesforce. So I tried putting the data in Oracle table and then perform the analysis.

Comment: If @mustaccio 's solution works, great. Otherwise, you might need some custom development. Maybe a .csv (or similar) dump? Maybe you can read in subsets using Oracle's external tables - and then recombine those subsets in some sort of normalised structure? Can you put a couple of sample records up on the web?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can't give a sample though as it is production data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your definition of "best method", but here's an option: Oracle 11g and later allow `CLOB`s as input to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, so you could write an anonymous block to read your DDL file using `DBMS_LOB` and pass the contents to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: I need to try this method and if this works then will mark this as the correct answer. Do you think this DDL file can take 30k characters?

Comment: From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits001.htm) - CLOB = (4GB - 1)